make hard corner rounded(mirror-modifier)
I am currently modelling a Mauser C96 and have a problem to make rounded corners even though I am familiar with the bevel tool. I want to make the front rounded like it is shown in the other picture. Can anyone help me because it is just beveling (+ unfortunately inwards) at the bottom of the front. Is the mirror modifier the problem? Thanks for any help.



Yes you could temporarily apply the Miror and bevel the vertical edge, but I wonder why you need so many horizontal edge loops? Maybe simplify?

Hey, thanks for your help! I have so many edge loops because I made Loop Cuts to make the shape of the thing around the trigger. But I have still the problem that the bevel is going inwards... Can I make a new object with the right half without the mirror modifier?(so that the right half is still there but it isn't mirrored anymore)

I'm not sure what you mean, you can apply the Mirror and anyway you can bring back afterwards (remove the half or use the Mirror bisect option). As for the horizontal edge loops you should be able to create the shapes without extending all these edge loops

thanks I managed to fix it more or less
